# Adding/removing RabbitMQ user tag from management UI without inputting password

Tags: rabbitmq

I have an administrator user that can add or remove user tag of another user, but as far as I know the the only way to do that from management UI is to also provide user password because there is only a single [form in the Admin tab that handle both update password and user tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqqqs.png). The form will throw an error modal if I did not provide the password since it is a mandatory input.

Is it possible to add/remove the tag without inputting the password from the management UI? I am aware that I can do this by using [`rabbitmqctl set_user_tags <username> <[tag]>`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/man/rabbitmqctl.8#set_user_tags) but I want to know how to do it using the management UI.

I am using RabbitMQ 3.12.6